# Does my Spanish work permit relate to an EU Blue Card?

Tags: working-visas, eu, spain, blue-card

I've been scouring the Internet for an answer to my situation but have come up short.

I am a non-EU citizen currently in Spain under Highly Qualified based on the Law 14/2013.

I've been told that this is equivalent to the EU blue card.

What I would like to know is:

(1) Do I need to apply for the EU blue card?
(2) If I do, can I just apply to transfer the permit?
(3) Would my current work permit allow me to easily look for jobs in other EU countries?